# This class is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iboutlet

When I try to run my application on the iPhone simulator, It crashes and I get this error:

```
2013-10-22 20:24:02.367 brainademy[46328:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0xcc6de90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ChooseGameViewController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01a0d5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x017908b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01a9d6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x01451c2e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
4   Foundation                          0x013bdf3b _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
5   Foundation                          0x013bd493 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
6   Foundation                          0x0141f94a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
7   UIKit                               0x007a4cd5 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x017a27d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
9   CoreFoundation                      0x01a08b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
10  UIKit                               0x007a382e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
11  UIKit                               0x007a55bb -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 165
12  UIKit                               0x00502fcb -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
13  UIKit                               0x005032f9 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
14  UIKit                               0x00501e9f -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543
15  UIKit                               0x0051642c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
16  UIKit                               0x00516999 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
17  UIKit                               0x00503c35 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
18  GraphicsServices                    0x0319e2eb _PurpleEventCallback + 776
19  GraphicsServices                    0x0319ddf6 PurpleEventCallback + 46
20  CoreFoundation                      0x01988dd5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
21  CoreFoundation                      0x01988b0b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
22  CoreFoundation                      0x019b37ec __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
23  CoreFoundation                      0x019b2b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
24  CoreFoundation                      0x019b294b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
25  UIKit                               0x005016ed -[UIApplication _run] + 840
26  UIKit                               0x0050394b UIApplicationMain + 1225
27  brainademy                          0x0000b01d main + 141
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x02e8c725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Most of the time, this is going to mean that I have something in my File's owner, an IBOutlet or IBAction that is not declared, yet this is not the case. I have looked at every single other question like this and none of them have helped.

ChooseGameViewController *IS* declared, so that shouldn't cause any problems, but I tried unhooking it from the File's owner, and when I do, and run my app, It crashes and instead of ChooseGameViewController it's ColorGameViewController. I tried removing every single one of my ViewController IBOutlets, and when I did that, I got other IBOutlets, like labels and buttons, that showed up in the error instead of ChooseGameViewController. I get no errors next to any of my outlets, like you usually would if you had an non-declared outlet.

I tried making a clean build, but that didn't work, and my File's owner is hooked up to the correct class (RootViewController)

This app was working fine just a while ago, and I just opened up Xcode today and I started getting these errors.

This is not a problem with non-declared outlets, because:

- All the outlets **ARE** declared
- I get no errors in the file's owner
- This error happens with every single *IBOutlet*, and IBOutlets only

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: It looks like these are getting sent to the Application object instead of a view controller.  Are these items hooked up to the correct place?

Comment: Yes they are, again it was working fine just a second ago @borrrden

Comment: Check the name of your ".xib" file, i think the issue is with xib filename and double check "reference Outlets" for the same. Good luck.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara the names are the same... Am I not importing AppDelegate somewhere?

Comment: @Domenico its due to "Reference outlet" you specified in your controller. are you using xcode5? then you need to make respective changes in `.plist` file. and do double check names, and `Reference Outlets`, AppDelegate is not required to import.

Comment: one more thing remove `Main nib file base name` key from your `.plist` file it will be done for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new Xcode project and copying everything over, which makes me think it had something to do with the me trying to add support for iPad.

This happens whenever I try to do this, even making a new application, making it universal, and making the new `.xib` file for iPad, and hooking it up via the project manager.

Even when I remove support for iPad the error above still shows, I think I have to do something with just changing the view controller using code.

Comment: An XIB occasionally get's mucked up, particularly when moving between different Xcode version.  I've found that it's usually fixed by opening the XIB (in the version of Xcode you want to use), making a change (eg, adding a label), and saving it.  Then open again, remove the added element, and save again.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't look `ChooseGameViewController` on `UIApplication`.

I guess your `AppDelegate` have a property `ChooseGameViewController` so you need to go to interface builder and make sure your outlets hook to `AppDelegate` not `UIApplication`

If you have source control, make a diff and see what's changed. Otherwise you can open `.xib` file using XML editor and check it does not contain `UIApplication` in unexpected place.

Comment: my `AppDelegate` Does not have any classes except `RootViewController`, also can you please specify what you are saying? Again, it was working fine just a second ago, and when I remove ChooseGameViewController, I get an error for something else, and I just keep getting errors for everything

Comment: It was working maybe due to your simulator/device contain old storyboard file (because xcode decided to not update it). You can try revert to a previous working version and do a rebuild to see if is working.

Comment: I don't really have a previous working version, and also, I just checked and deleted all of the methods files and header files and .xib files that I don't have in the project. No luck

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue when I deleted one IBOutlet property from a class. I see storyboard still keep the IBOutlet link even when deleting the IBOutlet property.

**Solution**

1. Find in your class if you deleted any Outlet property
2. Navigate to the storyboard find the object and Outlet link
   and remove

Hope this work for you.

Comment: key part of the question:

`-All the outlets ARE declared
-I get no errors in the file's owner`